# Detecting Artificial Patterns

Tags: opencv, pattern-recognition

I trained a classifier to detect a MacBeth colorchart which is an artificial pattern and should be easy to detect. Training was done detecting haarfeatures from 1500 negatives and 4000 positives using bg photos from google (http://tutorial-haartraining.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/data/negatives/) that were similar to the environment where the pattern is most probably to be found.

The statistics of the training seemed to be very reasonable:

```
===== TRAINING 9-stage =====

POS count : consumed   4000 : 4170

NEG count : acceptanceRatio    1500 : 0.00365317

Precalculation time: 3

|  N |    HR   |    FA   |

|   1|        1|        1|

|   2|        1|        1|

|   3|        1|        1|

|   4|    0.996| 0.865333|

|   5|    0.996| 0.865333|

|   6|  0.99625|    0.688|

|   7|  0.99525| 0.633333|

|   8|  0.99575| 0.517333|

|   9|  0.99525| 0.489333|
```

It went through all 10-stages and produced a 33kb XML cascade description file.

However when I try to find the pattern, it detects all sorts of things as the pattern.

Does anyone have an idea how to improve the settings or properly find that pattern?

Here are my training parameters:

```
PARAMETERS:

cascadeDirName: /training3

vecFileName: pos_samples_vec_004.vec

bgFileName: bg5.txt

numPos: 4000

numNeg: 1500

numStages: 10

precalcValBufSize[Mb] : 256

precalcIdxBufSize[Mb] : 256

stageType: BOOST

featureType: HAAR

sampleWidth: 32

sampleHeight: 32

boostType: GAB

minHitRate: 0.995

maxFalseAlarmRate: 0.5

weightTrimRate: 0.95

maxDepth: 1

maxWeakCount: 100

mode: ALL
```

Answer (score 0):

Increase the number of stages, a minimum of 20 stages are usually needed in order to achieve any amount of specificity in detection. Also keep track of the acceptance ratio in the negatives, the lower it is the better.